# ValueError exception when creating a column from other columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a column from two other columns in a `DataFrame`. 
Consider the 3-column data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random_list_1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
random_list_2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
random_list_3 = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)

df = pd.DataFrame({"p": random_list_1, "q": random_list_2, "r": random_list_3})
```

I create a new column from `"p"` and `"q"` with a function that will be given to `apply`. 
As a simple example:

```
def operate(row):
    return [row['p'], row['q']]
```

Here,

```
df['s'] = df.apply(operate, axis = 1)
```

evaluates correctly and creates a column `"s"`.

The issue appears when I am considering a data frame with a number of columns equal to the length of the list output by `operate`. So for instance with

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"p": random_list_1, "q": random_list_2})
```

evaluating this:

```
df2['s'] = df2.apply(operate, axis = 1)
```

throws a `ValueError` exception:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

What is happening?

As a workaround, I could make `operate` return tuples (which does not throw an exception) and then convert them to lists, but for performance sake I would prefer getting lists in one reading only of the `DataFrame`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both of the cases this work for me:

```
df["s"] = list(np.column_stack((df.p.values,df.q.values)))
```

Working with vectorized function is better than use apply. In this case the speed boost is `3x`. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)

Anyway I found your question interesting and I'd like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Great, thanks for `np.column_stack`. I was not aware of this function.

Comment: How would you go for a more complicated `operate` function? Say, the new row is not created from a list of the values of other rows (as is done in the simple `operate` function I gave); is there another function, in the vein of `column_stack`, that could help me doing vectorised operation on the columns?